# Windowed full-screen (borderless)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to run Skyrim in windowed full-screen mode, preferably without a border? I usually play in windowed mode but it's a bit sad. I do it to keep Fraps on loop buffer; full-screen cancels loop buffer every time I switch windows.